# Mobile app and accessing app through mobile website in browser

Tags: iphone, android, mobile

I have seen few apps having exact same UI when you access the app through stand alone app or through their mobile website. What are the pros and cons of both approaches while developing the app?

Edit - This is a general question. Not necessarily android. Iphone apps are also in similar categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a mobile website service that works in a HTML5 browser, that is a good business. But in order to show up in the Markets you need to have a native application as well. So the folks create a native application, that simply loads the website in a webview UI object, as a wrapper for the website.

Answer (score 0):

Take care if you are developping an app that is just a webview displaying a mobile website, because iOS app review team does not always like it.

I reccommand you to read carefully the [iOS App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). For example:

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
>
> 2.17 Apps that browse the web must use the iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript
>
> 12.3 Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected

Hope it helps